# IMAP Php bug - Workaround for this?

Tags: php, imap

Any work around for this problem?

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=28419

Comment: the status of the bug is listed as "bogus"

Comment: Any reason you're looking at a 6 year old bug? At most it seems to boil down to PHP being unable to report a line number if you use the @ to supress errors. PHP 4.3 is highly ancient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a bug in PHP. The page you linked to says:

> The error comes from the c-client
>   library. We can't do anything about it
>   so report to the c-client library
>   author(s) instead

Try updating your c-client/IMAP libraries (and PHP while you're at it -- PHP4 is deprecated)